# Ошибки при запуске приложения на Windows 7 x32

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-7, pyinstaller

Написал небольшую игру-викторину на `python 3.8 32-bit`, собрал в один файл с помощью `pyinstaller`. На Windows 10 x64 и x32 запускается и работает без нареканий, но на Windows 7 x32 при установке с флешки выдает эти ошибки: "Запуск программы невозможен, так как на компьютере отсутствует api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.dll. Попробуйте переустановить программу" и "Error loading Python DLL 'F:\dist\viktorinaimg\python39.dll'. LoadLibrary: не найден указанный модуль."

Answer (score 0):

Запускаемый файл нужно собирать на самой старой версии виндовс, на которой планируешь запускаться

Comment: а если нет возможности? дома только "десятка", а программу надо в школе сдавать.

Comment: @pch3l4 виртуалка в помощь сейчас это не проблема вообще.

Comment: не используй инсталеры - поставь в школе питон и запускай на нем